# Static dispatch without templates - storing type information in base classes

Tags: c++

I've been reading up on CRPT, static/dynamic dispatching, and have been wondering why the following pattern never comes up:

The idea is to store some type information in the base class, a tag per-se. We can then write `switch` statements when given a `Base` pointer.

```
struct Base {
    enum Type {
        Foo, 
        Bar
    };

    Type type;

    Base(Type type_) : type(type_) 
    {
    }
};

struct Foo final : Base {

    int foo;

    Foo(int val) : Base{Type::Foo}, foo{val} { }

    int getValue() const { return foo; }
};

struct Bar final : Base {

    int bar;

    Bar(int val) : Base{Type::Bar}, bar(val) { }

    int getValue() const { return bar; }
};

int someFunc(Base* base) {
    switch(base->type) {
        case Base::Type::Foo: 
            {
                Foo& tmp = static_cast<Foo&>(*base);
                return tmp.getValue();
            }
        case Base::Type::Bar:
            {
                Bar& tmp = static_cast<Bar&>(*base);
                return tmp.getValue();
            }
        default:
            return 0;
    };
}
```

I've compared this approach with classic dynamic dispatching (usual polymorphism), and performing `dynamic_cast`, and surprisingly I could observe sizeable speedups everytime.

Here's a list of advantages(+)/disadvantages(-) I see with this approach:
+No vtable
+Can always `static_cast`, don't pay the large cost of `dynamic_cast`
-Need to additionally store the type information (this should already be available through `typeinfo` an)
-Difficult to expand, we need to add new switch cases for every new derived type
-Shared interface between objects, but still need to downcast

In a use case where we know that the number of derived types is quite constrained and will virtually never be expanded.
Why would this be a bad approach if we're really aiming to be as quick as possible?
Is this theoretically faster or am I just getting lucky with my micro-benching because of inlinging or other factors?
Are there any other pitfalls?

---

Comment: This pattern was in use since dawn of times, way before C++ or OOP proper was invented. Given that its advantages are limited and disadvantages are numerous and hard to overcome, its use is not very widespread these days. Between virtual functions and `std::variant`, there just aren't that many places where this particular implementation of dynamic dispatch is competitive. (The dispatch is dynamic, rather than static; I have no idea where "static" in your title comes from).

Comment: It looks to me like you've just hand-written an extremely specialized version of `std::variant`. I might question the validity of your benchmarks. Did you compile with optimizations forced all the way down to 0? Simple benchmarks like this have a funny tendency to get aggressively optimized into "return 0", and the whole program just disappears. Is everything about the two programs exactly the same, save for the type of dispatch? I'd be interested to see your methodology, if you have it available and wouldn't mind editing it into your post.

Comment: Obviously, when your base class has dozens of functions and you have many derived classes, it become hard to maintain as you have to update each and every `switch`. This is very error prone comparer to virtual functions where you only need to provide functions that differs or are marked as pure virtual. Also, as soon as you need to put them in a container, you need a virtual destructor anyway. And unless the type is known at compile time, there is no reason why the `switch` version would be faster in any measurable way.